# Organization of singular vectors in the SVD decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Let $U$ be a unitary matrix for which one wants to compute the SVD decomposition. One option is to decompose $U$ using its real and imaginary parts, i.e. $U_R$ and $U_I$ respectively. Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
U_R &= V_1CX^\dagger,\\
U_I &= V_2SX^\dagger.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now it must be that $V_2=V_1F$ or $V_1=V_2F$, where $F$ is a diagonal matrix with $\pm1$'s on the diagonal. The question is a little bit weird, but suppose that the singular values which are the diagonal elements of $C$ and $S$ are real. Now it must be that

$$U = V_1(C+iFS)X^\dagger,$$

where $C+iFS$ is diagonal unitary. What is the order in which the eigenvectors have to be arranged such that all the equations are fulfilled?

In fact, I know that $U_R=V_1CX^\dagger$ is fulfilled (using numerics), but it's giving me trouble to check that $U_I=V_2SX^\dagger$ and $F$ is diagonal. In some sense, $V_1$ and $X$ (and up to some degree the singular values in $C$) fix the order of the basis in $V_2$, but there is still some room for arbitrary placement of the singular vectors in $V_2$. With some arragenment,  $U_I\neq V_2SX^\dagger$ but $F$ is diagonal, and with other $U_I=V_2SX^\dagger$ but $F$ is non-diagonal. A particular example as an answer will suffice, I just guess it will have to reproduce the above "wrong" orderings.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Every singular value of a unitary matrix is equal to $1$, so singular value decompositions of a unitary matrix just correspond to ways as writing it as a product of two other unitary matrices. E.g. $U = U \times I \times I^T$ is a SVD, as is $U = I \times I \times (U^T)^T$.

Comment: Not quite. Check that the $U$ is decomposed in real and imaginary parts, so if one part is not zero, then $U_R$ and $U_I$ have singular values not trivial. So the point is to find, if you want, $\cos\theta$ ($U_R$) or $\sin\theta$ ($U_I$). Of course they must fulfill that $|\lambda_R + i \lambda_I|=1$, but $\lambda_R$ (or $\lambda_I$) are not trivial. Check also that the right eigenvectors of both parts is $X^\dagger$, so digging up more I found that this is the "generalized SVD", in the sense of van Loan.